# Custom Search works on all pages except front

Tags: search

I have a custom search block in my header. When I search for something i am redirected to a new page and shown my products (this is the desired effect). The problem I'm having is on the front page. When I search for a product on my front page my front page is reloaded. I assume this has to do with aliases, but I have not messed with them on any of the pages so I'm not sure why it doesn't work on my front page, but works perfectly on all the other pages.  Any help would be great.

Thanks!

update: I solved the issue by replacing my search with and advance search. If anyone knows why a custom search wasn't working for me, I'm still interested in knowing why.